# Manipulating sample json lists using Python/ Spark on Databricks

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Attempting to logically parse through the following sample json list:

```
FruitJson = [
 ('{"num":100, "fruit" : ["apple", "peach", "grape", "melon"]}',), 
 ('{"num":101, "fruit" : ["melon", "apple", "mango", "banana"]}',),  
]
```

Ideal Output:

| fruit | count |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 2 |
| melon | 2 |
| peach | 1 |
| grape | 1 |
| mangno | 1 |
| banana | 1 |

I managed to get the first row of the list into a dataframe, but unable to progress further from here:

```
dbutils.fs.put("/temp/test.json",'{"num":100, "fruit" : ["apple", "peach", "grape", "melon"]}'\
'{"num":101, "fruit" : ["melon", "apple", "mango", "banana"]}',True)
df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json('/temp/test.json')
display(df)
```

You advice is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Updated thread with what i've tried. Basically I managed to upload only the first row into a json.file and then used spark.read.option("multiline","true").json('/temp/test.json') to store data into a dataframe. Been stuck here for a while. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `multiline` option should be `False`, not `True`. `multiline=False` means your JSON has multiple lines, one row per line. [Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json)

Second, what you're trying to achieve is a simple aggregation, but you will need to [`explode`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) the list to multiple rows first.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('fruit', F.explode('fruit'))
    .groupBy('fruit')
    .agg(
        F.count('*').alias('cnt')
    )
    .show()
)

# +------+---+
# | fruit|cnt|
# +------+---+
# | grape|  1|
# | apple|  2|
# | mango|  1|
# |banana|  1|
# | melon|  2|
# | peach|  1|
# +------+---+
```

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate all your help here. Explode was the missing link on my end.